# How can I invoke function from another function?

Tags: c#

I'm new on the C# and I have one question. I have one function for this job.

The function is static:

```
   FilterMethods.GetEmpDiscount(item.campaigns)   
//item.campaings type  a Class,  this function return decimal value.
```

How Can I Invoke this function at other function.

Comment: No, you can call everywhere. Prefixe by the class like you do in your sample.

Comment: by using `FilterMethods.GetEmpDiscount(myCampaigns)`?

Comment: `How Can I Invoke this function at other function` you don't, just call it... Also `HandleException Class` what does this question have to do with `Exception`?

Comment: Yes. FilterMethods seems to be a Helper with statics methods. You can call statics methods with class as prefix. FilterMethods is a class, isn't it ?

Comment: @KhalilLazhar: That is incorrect. Static methods can be called from anywhere (both static and class methods). I think you may be getting confused with the fact that class methods cannot be called from inside a static method (since the static scope is independent of any particular class instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void DoSomething()
{

}

static void DoSomethingElse()
{ 
    DoSomething();
}
```

But this only works if the calling function is static as well.

If they are in different classes you have to write 'classname.DoSomething();' while classname is the name of the class which contains the 'DoSomething()' method.

Keep in mind that the [access-modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers) are valid.